# How do I plot two data streams in Numbers as a graph?

Tags: mac, numbers, iwork

I have two different streams of fractional values I want to visualize using Numbers for Mac.

They both have one value per line and both look would look something like this (with different values obviously):

```
0.04
0.1
0.05
0.0993
1.3
0.534
...
```

And I basically want it to have the index (so 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) as the x axis and the amount (in seconds) on the y axis, and have the two data streams. And I'd like to have it as a line graph or a bar graph.

I can't figure out how to do this however.

Answer (score 1):

Add a chart, I used this one:

[image: Chart to add]

Then click [Add Chart Data] and select the columns for the data streams

[image: select data]

Comment: My issue with that is that it puts the first one as the x axis and the second as the y axis, which isn't what I want, I want both to be the y axis but on separate curves, and their index on the x axis.

Comment: that's not what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/TglR5Qq.png

Comment: How do you get the numbers on the side? They don't show up for me

Comment: I added them manually. If you type 1, then 2, select both cells and drag the yellow circle down

Comment: Is there a way without doing it manually? That's incredibly tedious for thousands of items

Comment: Hmm, lemme see if I can get it to work without that.

Comment: When I do it without the left-hand numbers, it works but puts no title on X axis, which can be remedied by going to the inspector -> axis -> X -> category labels